# Destructor vs member function race again

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've already seen similar question: [Destructor vs member function race](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461981/destructor-vs-member-function-race)
.. but didn't find the answer for the following. Suppose we have a class owning some worker thread. Destructor of the class can look like:

```
~OurClass
{
    ask_the_thread_to_terminate;
    wait_for_the_thread_to_terminate;
    ....
    do_other_things;
}
```

The question is: may we call OurClass's member functions in the worker thread as we are sure all these calls will be done before ***do_other_things*** in the destructor?

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers. I've just been confused by the following statement from C++ standard: "Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists;"

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. Destruction of member variables willonly start after `do_other_things` completes its execution. It is safe to call member functions before object gets destructed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you kinda can do that, but it's easy to make a mistake this way. For example, if you do something like:

```
~OurClass
{
    delete *memberPointer_; 
    ask_the_thread_to_terminate; // the thread calls OurClass::foo();
    wait_for_the_thread_to_terminate;
    ....
    do_other_things
}

void OurClass::foo()
{
    memberPointer->doSomething();
}
```

you will be in trouble. It also makes it harder to read through the code. So you will have to be careful with the order of operations and stuff like that. In general if it's possible to change the architecture to avoid such complicated constructions, I would suggest to do it.

Comment: That’s why *proper* resource handing is important. The `delete` statement in the destructor is a classic mistake. Use smart pointers instead, this ensures that such a mistake cannot occur.

Answer (score 1):

The *implicit* destruction of any data members occurs after execution of the last explicit line of your destructor, so all those data members are still fully functional whilst you wait for the thread. Hence, you must only avoid any premature *explicit* destruction of any data members (as exemplified in SingerOfTheFall's pathological code).

Comment: I should remember the "pathological code" expression, sounds fancy ;)